# Timed email reminder if/else

Tags: php, mysql, email, datetime, if-statement

I am working on a reservation system that allows people 72 hours (3 days) to confirm their registration by clicking a link. I want to sent out a reminder email after 48 hours (2 days) if the registration is not confirmed yet. If not confirmed after 72 hours (3 days), the registration will be removed from the database.

However, I have no clue what to do with the if/else statements. My logic died on my today.
Can somebody give me a hand with the right if and else statements? Much appreciated!

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<?php

// Connect to database
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE reserved='yes' AND confirmed='no'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

// set reservation time
$datetime = $row['datetime'];
$datetime -> modify('+3 days'); 

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

foreach $query as $row {
   if ($datetime > $now) {
        //it still has time. sent reminder if less than 24 hours left.
   } else {
       //time has passed, set registration inactive.
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do the date comparisons in the database?

```
SELECT *
FROM reservations
WHERE reserved='yes' AND confirmed='no' AND
      datetime > now() - interval 3 day AND datetime <= now() - interval 2 day;
```

This will return only the rows you want to contact, so you don't need additional logic (for the `datetime`) on the application side.

Comment: Of course.. I see I am making things complicated unnecessary